# URL Rewrite rule in .NET to force www but ignore http(s)

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I'm looking to set up a rewrite rule in my web.config file which forces URLs to use the 'www' sub-domain. This is done like so:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Add WWW" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions>
       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

However, the project is running multiple websites on multiple domains, some of which use SSL and some don't.

The code above hard-codes `http://` into the redirect. What I'm looking to do is to abstract this such that the http or https protocols are maintained during the redirect without being hard-coded.

Some examples of the desired results are:

- http://olddomain.com > http://www.newdomain.com
- https://someolddomain.com > https://www.somenewdomain.com

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a [reference](http://jeffgraves.me/2012/11/06/maintain-protocol-in-url-rewrite-rules/) which explains one approach in doing this.  It uses rewrite key/value pairs as a 'variable' in the action url, as (as far as I can find out) there's no way currently to grab the protocol as a native variable inside the rule.

The rule has been modified as follows, which should do what's required:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
          <rule name="Add www maintain https" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <conditions>
             <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{MapSSL:{HTTPS}}www.{C:0}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
       </rule>
    </rules>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="MapSSL" defaultValue="http://">
            <add key="ON" value="https://" />
            <add key="OFF" value="http://" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

There's also another [reference](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action) which includes this amongst alternative ways to achieve the same thing.